# Android TextView with Custom background?

Tags: android, textview, android-relativelayout

I need a "Button" that would have a texture background, and dynamic text. The end result should be like this, but the background is a textured picture.
[image: Custom Button with Text:]
I tried to use a `RelativeLayout` with a `TextView` inside, but the problem is that the result `CustomView` does not `wrap_content` in width/height.

Here is the `custom_button`**XML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button_selector"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the `Code`:

```
public class CustomButton extends RelativeLayout {

private LayoutInflater mInflater;

private RelativeLayout mContainer;

private TextView mTextView;

public CustomButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    customInit(context);
}

public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    customInit(context);
}

public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    customInit(context);
}

private void customInit(Context ctx) {
    mContainer = (RelativeLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cutom_button_view, this, true);

    mTextView = (TextView) mContainer.findViewById(R.id.tv);
}

public RelativeLayout getContainer() {
    return mContainer;
}

public TextView getTextView() {
    return mTextView;
}
}
```

This is how I use it at the moment, and it **works**:

```
<com.myapp.views.CustomButton
                android:id="@+id/btn"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"/>
```

But I want to use it like this (for dynamic text), and it **won't work**:

```
<com.myapp.views.CustomButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

It will actually stretch across the whole screen, ignoring the layout rules.
If this solution is a bad idea, could you recommend an alternative that would produce the same results?

Comment: whats wrong with `TextView.setBackground` ?

Comment: it simply doesn't center the text on the image... I have to use padding, but it breaks with dynamic text length. Actually, the core of my problem is the dynamic text length :(

Comment: whats wrong with `TextView.setGravity` ?

Comment: try to use nine patch image.

Comment: Try setting your `TextView` `height` and `width` to `match_parent` as well, and keep the `gravity:center`. Also (although it doesn't really matter) a `RelativeLayout` is somewhat overkill for the task at hand, a `FrameLayout` would work just as well.

Comment: Have you considered using button? In my opinion setting background to button would do the work which will center the text. Is your background static image i.e not xml or 9patch that stretch according to tontent?

Comment: The 9patch image that constitutes the background is very large itself (200h x 300w px at xxhdpi)because is texturized. If I add it as a `background` property to a `TextView`, the text will have very little space and it won't fit. This is why I went for the "Container with Background + Textview" approach.
For this same reason - background image is too large - `TextView`, `Button`, none will work, because there is not enough space for the text.

Answer (score 4):

You need to Shape file for that..

try out this.

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="56dp" />

    <solid android:color="Color Whaterver You Want" />

    <padding android:bottom="4dp" android:left="4dp" android:right="4dp" android:top="4dp" />
</shape>
```

Put this xml file under res/drawal folder.

now just in Your view pass this attribute..

`android:background="@drawable/your file name"`

Hop it works for you..

Answer (score 0):

Custom layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/my_background">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Custom layout java:

```
public class CustomButton extends FrameLayout {


private RelativeLayout mContainer;

private TextView mTextView;

public CustomButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
    customInit(context);
}

public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    customInit(context);
}

public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    customInit(context);
}

private void customInit(Context ctx) {
    LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.custom_button_viewa, this, true);
    mContainer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
}

public RelativeLayout getContainer() {
    return mContainer;
}

public TextView getTextView() {
    return mTextView;
}
}
```

Now can be used as:

```
 <com.androidbolts.databindingsample.model.CustomButton
        android:id="@+id/customButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```